# json response get values in android

Tags: android, json

I am new to android and struggling to get the values of the json object. Can someone help me out?

the json returned from the server is `{"status":"active"}`

I'm using Android Asynchronous Http Client library..

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);
                t.setText(j.getJSONObject(0).getString('status'));//this doesn't set the text to the status
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems you need to understand the basics of JSON data. Like {} represents JSON object, [] represents Json array.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);
t.setText(j.getJSONObject(0).getString("status"));
```

with:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);
t.setText(j.getString("status"));
```

if you getting String in response you have to try this hope it helps you

EDIT:

But in your case JSONObject is coming in response So you can try directly like this:

```
t.setText(response.getString("status"));
```

Comment: it says can't resolve toString() which library do I import?

Comment: check my edited answer. try t.setText(response.getString("status")); directly in place of JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);
t.setText(j.getJSONObject(0).getString("status"));

Comment: if this works mark this as a correct answer so others getting help from this. Happy to help you :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

because `{"status":"active"}` is a JSONObject.

and use

```
 t.setText(jsonObject.getString("status"));
```

Full code is

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                t.setText(jsonObject.getString("status"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }
        }
```

As per other answers It is waste to create a new `JSONObject`. So use it directly

```
   public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    t.setText(response.getString("status"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                }
            }
```

> Note: **creating more instances is for bad performance**

Comment: Thanks. I know yeah since I would have done obj[0].status in javascript but it didn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

It's already a JSON Object as incoming parameter You don't need to create external object of JSON Array or JSON Object 
Try This.

```
t.setText(response.getString("status"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use direct JSONObject for getting value

```
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

       try {
            t.setText(response.getString("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not familiar with JSON object and JSON array. I will recommend you to print your response on `Log.i("response", response.toString())` then after checking response from [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) You perform actual stuff.

see [JSON Array](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JSON object](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) also

Answer (score 0):

Use optString instead of getString,because if you are using getString and the key "status" not exit then app may be crash.

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {

              t.setText(j.getJSONObject(0).optString('status'));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }
        }
```